# jwt config secret file push on git

Tags: node.js, express, config, jwt

I work on an node, express mongoose API with JWT (json web token). I don't push my `config.js` file to keep secret my key (.gitignore -> config.js) but when travis run my test with **mocha** it return the  error : `Cannot find module './config'`.

I try to mock it but it doesn't work, so :

- I can push my config.js file, it's not unsafe ?
- How can i mock my require dependency config.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should push config.js in repo. But you should make it like this:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
'use strict';

module.exports = function () {
    return {
        SERVER_HOST: process.env.HOST,
        OTP: {
            LENGTH: 6,
            DURATION: 300000, //ms
        },
        TWILIO: {
            ACCOUNT_SID: process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
            AUTH_TOKEN: process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN,
            MESSAGE_FROM: process.env.TWILIO_MESSAGE_FROM
        },
        JWT: {
            SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
            ALGORITHM: 'HS512',
            ISSUER: 'GOHAN'
        },
        BCRYPT: {
            SALT_ROUNDS: 10
        },
        EMAIL: {
            USER: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
            PASSWORD: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
        },
        REDIS: {
            HOST: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
            PORT: process.env.REDIS_PORT
        },
        AWS: {
            ACCESS_KEY_ID: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            S3: {
                PROFILE_PIC_BUCKET: process.env.AWS_S3_PROFILE_PIC_BUCKET,
                VOICE_MESSAGES_BUCKET: process.env.AWS_S3_VOICE_MESSAGES_BUCKET,
                REGION: process.env.AWS_S3_REGION,
                SIGNED_URL_EXPIRY: 900
            }
        },
        TCP_SERVER: {
            PASSWORD: process.env.TCP_SERVER_PASSWORD
        },
        GOOGLE_API_KEY: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        APN: {
            CONNECTION: {
                production: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'),
                cert: process.env.APN_CERT,
                passphrase: process.env.APN_PASSPHRASE,
                key: process.env.APN_CERT
            },
            FEEDBACK: {
                address: process.env.APN_FEEDBACK_ADDRESS,
                cert: process.env.APN_CERT,
                key: process.env.APN_CERT,
                passphrase: process.env.APN_PASSPHRASE,
                interval: process.env.APN_INTERVAL,
                batchFeedback: process.env.APN_BATCHFEEDBACK
            }
        },
        FCM: {
            API_KEY: process.env.FCM_API_KEY,
            RETRY_LIMIT: 3
        }
    };
};
```

All the code should be independent of the environment, this is the purpose of environment variables. Not to ensure safety.

You can load up the environment variables before running your app.

You can have different .env files for testing, dev and prod environments also.

EDIT:
The above config.js is from a project of mine.

Comment: it's not possible to create a config.spec.js file only for my test ? when i remove config.js in app it's not work, i have this : 
Uncaught TypeError: secret must be a string or buffer.